# Пользователь в линукс не может ипользовать sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo, su

создал пользователя ввёл его в группу wheel

```
useradd -s /bin/bash -m -p 12345 -G wheel tom
```

так как в новых версиях линукса по умолчанию группа wheel отключена, я ее так сказать включил.

1. до этого создал группу wheel,
2. раскомментировал строку **`auth required pam_wheel.so`** в /etc/pam.d/su
3. добавил в `/etc/sudoers` строку **`%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL`**

когда меняю на этого пользователя `su tom`
пользователь **tom** пытаеться использовать sudo выходит это и просит написать пароль
даже если ввожу правильный пароль, говорит, что не правильный.

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

группы у **tom'a**: tom wheel

UPD
кстати, сейчас попробовал авторизоваться через графич. интерфейс, то так он вообще не заходит. Когда ввожу пароль пишет Sorry, that's didnt
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создал несколько пользователей, у всех тоже самое

Comment: Чей пароль вводите-то?

Comment: Может лучше добавить в `sudo` и `adm`?

Comment: «раскомментировал строку auth required pam_wheel.so» — вот это ты зачем сделал?

Comment: @Fat-Zer чтобы группа wheel была доступна. В документации читал. Но видимо группа wheel сейчас не используется поэтому ее урали

Answer (score 2):

> раскомментировал строку auth required pam_wheel.so в /etc/pam.d/su

На самом деле это всего то выключил доступ к `su` (не путать с `sudo`) пользователям не состоящим в группе `wheel`. ИМХО сегодня так мало-кто делает, поэтому глаз за это у всех сразу и зацепился... Но если считаешь это правильным, то пожалуйста, но когда делаешь нечто подобное, советую понимать, что именно ты делаешь. Никакого отношения к «доступности» группы `wheel` оно не имеет отношения

> …так как в новых версиях линукса по умолчанию группа wheel отключена…
>
> …Но видимо группа wheel сейчас не используется…

По поводу группы `wheel` — в ней нет ничего магического, это обычная группа… В некоторых дистрибутивах она есть изначально, в некоторых — нет; некоторые администраторы заводят её себе, а некоторые — нет; в современных дебиано-бубунтах, например, для доступа к `sudo` из коробки группа с говорящим именем `sudo`.

Так что говорить, что она «не используется» или «отключена» — излишнее обобщение.

> даже если ввожу правильный пароль, говорит, что не правильный.

В 99 случаях из ста, если система говорит, что пароль неправильный, то он **действительно неправильный**. Подозреваю, что пароль ты пытаешься установить в ключе `-p` команды `useradd`. В таком случае это так не работает, ключ `-p` принимает уже шифрованный пароль; подробности смотри здесь: [Можно ли создавать пользователя одновременно с вводом пароля из переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1022068/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9/1022091#1022091), а на практике пароль стоит устанавливать утилитой `passwd`.

Если всё же пароль правильный, то могу предположить, одно из следующего:

- `sudo` настроен так, что требует ввода пароля пользователя пользователя на которого совершается переход (встречается например в opensuse), в таком случае вводи пароль root'а или настрой sudo (см. содержимое /etc/sudoers).
- Из коробки есть дополнительные модули pam, которые по тем или иным причинам режут вход новодобавленным пользователям. В таком случае стоит смотреть правила pam (в первую очередь /etc/pam.d/{system,common}-auth или нечто подобное) и логи.
- Другие ещё более странные причины.

---

В остальном к действиям настройки в вопросе нареканий нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема авторизации под данным пользователем в пароле.

Для корректной установки пароля при добавлении пользователя следует шифровать его:

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p `openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz 12345` -G wheel tom
```

либо без шифрования устанавливать дополнительно:

```
useradd -m tom
#Если пользователь уже создан, то использовате только команду ниже.
passwd tom --stdin <<< 12345
```

[Доп.инфо в соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1022078/341547)

Возможно при корректном пароле проблем с авторизацией не возникнет

Answer (score 0):

причём здесь auth required pam_wheel.so ?
и зачем вам группа wheel ?

Для того чтобы пользователь мог пользоваться sudo его нужно добавить в файл `/etc/sudoers` (он может находится и в другом месте) вручную в файл, а лучше с помощью команды `visudo`.

```
tom   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

либо включив его в группу (любую) например `users`, если таких пользователей много и добавить группу, ограничив группу необходимыми командами:

```
%users  ALL=/sbin/mount /mnt/cdrom, /sbin/umount /mnt/cdrom, /bin/ping
```

либо

```
%users        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

когда вводите `sudo ping 8.8.8.8` , то нужно ввести пароль от `tom`

Comment: а если у меня 1000 пользователей и всех нужно вводить в /etc/sudoers? бред.    создать группу и в  /etc/sudoers дать права на нее и всех 1000 пользователей в группу.     а группа wheel, для того, чтобы пользователи имели доступ к sudo.    Раньше группа wheel для этого предназначалась, но сейчас ее убрали, как я понял.  Поэтому я задал вопрос.

Comment: Дорогой мой, я же написал:
группа может быть любой ! если у тебя 1000 пользователей. а если у тебя из 3-5 ?
Выбирай как тебе удобнее. бреда тут нет никакого.
а группа wheel и сейчас используется для этого но в других операционках, например в freebsd.