# Можно ли создавать пользователя одновременно с вводом пароля из переменной

Tags: bash

Вопрос касается команды `useradd`, у меня создается пользователь через скрипт и пароль берется от сервера к которому подключается скрипт, но когда я записываю пароль в переменную и пытаюсь сделать создание пользователя без `ввода пароля руками`, у меня выводится ошибка. Подскажите как можно создать пользователя с паролем и все одной командой без ввода данных.

**For example**

```
PASSWORD=12345
USER=ivan
useradd -m -d -p /home/$USER $USER $PASSWORD
```

И вот когда я пытался писать с параметром `-p` мне выдает ошибку `неверный домашний каталог`

Либо такой пример, пароль хранится в переменной пытаюсь перенаправить в ввод, но тоже ошибка

```
passwd $USER < $PASSWORD
```

Как быть в данной ситуации? Просто я пытаюсь сохранить значение пароля в переменной и затем, `без ввода пароля` создать пользователя, как автоматически. Возможно ли?

Answer (score 3):

```
USER=test
PASSWORD=testpass111
```

---

С переменными все работает в таком виде, протестировал на CentOS6.5

```
useradd -m $USER
passwd $USER --stdin <<< $PASSWORD
```

---

По поводу вашей команды:

```
useradd -m -d -p /home/$USER $USER $PASSWORD
```

`-p`, `--password` ПАРОЛЬ
*Шифрованное значение пароля, которое возвращает функция crypt(3). По умолчанию пароль отключён.*
Т.е. при установке нового пароля, его нужно шифровать.

---

**UPD: протестировал, установка пароля при добавлении пользователя работает корректно:**

```
useradd -m -p `openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz $PASSWORD` $USER
```

---

Так же по поводу создания домашнего каталога с именем пользователя достаточно указать ключ `-m`, ключ `-d` использовать только для переопределения в каталог отличный от `/home/имя пользователя`
Так же в синтаксисе команды принято использовать ключ - значения, вместо перечисления ключей а затем параметров.

Answer (score 2):

```
user=ivan
password=12345; 


# добавить пользователя
/usr/sbin/useradd "$user" -m -d "home/$user"
# изменить пароль
echo "$user:$password" | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

Как-то так у меня получилось.